# コマンドはdocker-compose.ymlとDockerfileのどちらで定義するほうがいい？

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[こちら](http://docs.docker.jp/compose/django.html)にDocker-ComposeでDjangoとPostgreSQLを動かす例があります。

この例ではdocker-compose.ymlでコマンドを定義していますが、サービス定義で`build`を指定している場合にはDockerfileの`CMD`でもコマンドを定義することができます。

[docker-composeのcommand](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/command)
[DockerfileのCMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd)

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
# CMD <-ここでもコマンドを定義できる
```

このような場合にはdocker-compose.ymlの`command`とDockerfileの`CMD`のどちらで定義したほうがいいのでしょうか？
それぞれのメリット／デメリットがあれば教えてください。

Answer (score 3):

`docker-compose.yml` で command を書くと、`docker-compose up` を実行したときに、その内容が実行されます。`Dockerfile` で指定した CMD はこのときは無視されます。

なので、`docker run` で特定のコマンドを実行したいときは `Dockerfile` の CMD に書けばいいし、`docker-compose up` でコマンドを実行したいときは `docker-compose.yml` に記述すればいいと思います。

(ただ、`docker run` の引数で実際に実行するコマンドを上書きできたりもします)

Comment: docker-composeで作成したコンテナを単独で「docker run で特定のコマンドを実行したいとき」というのはどんな時ですか？その場合は`docker-compose run`を使うと思うのですが。

Comment: 例えば、ビルドしたイメージの内容を確認するためにコンテナ内で /bin/sh を立ち上げるようなユースケースがあると思います。`CMD` で Django イメージのデフォルトのコマンドが指定されても、`docker run -ti DJANGO_IMAGE /bin/sh` のようにすることで、`CMD` の内容を `/bin/sh` で上書きしてシェルを起動できます。

ただ、おっしゃる通り、この例ではウェブサーバを docker-compose の中でビルドしているためネームタグがつかないので、あまりいい例ではないかもしれないです...。